# How can I interpolate a class constant in a Spring `@Value` annotation?

Tags: java, spring

I want to let Spring assign a property value.

```
public class Foobar {

    @Value("${example.property.foo:bar}")
    private String foo;
}
```

Let's say I want to refer to `example.property.foo` in several different places, so I'd rather assign the flag as a constant on Foobar:

```
public class Foobar {
    public static final String FOO_PROPERTY_FLAG = "example.property.foo";
}
```

The setting of `example.property.foo=whatever` happens elsewhere (as a system property, or in a `@TestPropertySource`).

How can I refer to `FOO_PROPERTY_FLAG` in the annotation? This works:

```
@Value("${" + FOO_PROPERTY_FLAG + ":bar}")
```

But it's kind of ugly. Can I use the `"#{}"` expression syntax here somehow?

```
@Value("${#{FOO_PROPERTY_FLAG}:bar}")  // doesn't work; value is never injected
```

Comment: I have the same question. Curious to see the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
public static final String KEY = "propertyName";

@Value("#{T(a.b.c.package.MyConstants).KEY}")
```

The important part is to specify package and class. Otherwise spring will try to lookup constant in `BeanExpressionContext` which is actually executing your SpEL

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me, as I need to inject the **value** of the system property stored at `KEY`, not `KEY` itself. Therefore I need the `${}` operator. When I try `@Value("${#{T(a.b.c.package.MyConstants).KEY}}")`, I get an `IllegalArgumentException: could not resolve placeholder` error. Edited the question to clarify this a bit.

Comment: Okay, spring doesn't allow to do that using SpEL: `Finally, while you can write a SpEL expression in @Value, such expressions are not processed from Application property files.`. However you can load properties into `Properties` bean and access them in some kind of `#{myProps.getProperty(T(a.b.c.MyClass).KEY)}`. Ugly though.

Comment: In my case, my value is in an array where the keys are constants.
The array used is jobParameters from Spring Batch.
If it can help somebody, to access a value from this array, I have done :
`@Value("#{jobParameters[T(a.b.c.package.MyConstants).KEY]}")
private String myValue;`

Answer (score 1):

```
private @Value("${propertyName}") String propertyField;
```

No getters or setters!

With the properties being loaded via the config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="classpath:propertyFile.properties" name="propertiesBean"/>
```

There's also the totally non-Xml version:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:propertyFile.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

Make sure and add in the namespace URI `xmlns:p="springframework.org/schema/p"`; to use the `p:` prefixed attributes